# SQL LIKE operator not working for comma-separated lists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is my data:

```
Column:
8
7,8
8,9,18
6,8,9
10,18
27,28
```

I only want rows that have and `8` in it. When I do:

```
Select * 
from table 
where column like '%8%'
```

I get all of the above since they contain an `8`. When I do:

```
Select * 
from table 
where column like '%8%' 
   and column not like '%_8%'
```

I get:

```
8
8,9,18
```

I don't get `6,8,9`, but I need to since it has `8` in it.

Can anyone help get the right results?

Comment: What is it that you expect `column not like '%_8%'` to do? Because `'6,8,9'` *is* `like '%_8%'`. (Actually, the strange thing is that you *do* get `'8,9,18'`, since it's *also* `like '%_8%'`.)

Comment: Why are you storing data as a comma-separated list? If you properly normalized your data you would not have this problem.

Comment: Note that `_` is a wildcard for _any single character_. This might be the confusing part?

Comment: The `_` implies that there must be a character there @ruakh, the reason why the OP gets what they do is because they all start with 8 and therefore the 8 doesn't have a leading character (I think :-).

Comment: @Ben: Sure, `'8,9,18'` has an `8` that's not preceded by another character, but it also has an `8` that *is* preceded by another character. `'8,9,18' LIKE '%_8%'` should be "true", and `'8,9,18' NOT LIKE '%_8%'` should be "false". I find it hard to believe that the leading `8` would trick SQL Server 2008 into not noticing the non-leading `8`; that would be a pretty embarrassing bug.

Comment: @Ruakh is right. Only one row, the one with `'8'` should be returned with these data.

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: SSRS sends in values as a comma delimited string when you allow multiple values for a parameter. Advanced. But it doesn't really mean you are storing data in this fashion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE column LIKE '%,8,%' OR column LIKE '%,8' OR column LIKE '8,%' OR Column='8';
```

But I **must** say storing data like this is highly inefficient, indexing won't help here for example, and you should consider altering the way you store your data, unless you have a really good reason to keep it this way.

**Edit:**

I highly recommend taking a look at @Bill Karwin's Link in the question's comment:

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: Instead of that `WHERE column LIKE '%,8,%' OR column LIKE '%,8' OR column LIKE '8,%'` you could have simply put `WHERE ',' + column + ',' LIKE '%,8,%'` - just personal preference probably... EDIT: nevermind, looks like someone else already answered this :)

Answer (score 9):

You could use:

```
WHERE ','+col+',' LIKE '%,8,%'
```

And the obligatory admonishment: avoid storing lists, bad bad, etc.

Comment: They probably didn't like that you told them not to break the relational model with a relational database.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
where
    col like '8,%'
    or col like '%,8,%'
    or col like '%,8'
    or col = '8'
```

But ideally, as bluefeet suggests, normalizing this data instead of storing as delimited text will save you all kinds of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem searching for the underscore character **'_'** which was returning extra results in the result set in SQL Server.

I tried escaping the character with a backslash but this did not work.

I was unable to use the ***WHERE CHAR_INDEX('_', column_name) > 1*** technique since my instance did not have that feature enabled.

Also searching using the encoded hex value resulted in the same incorrect behaviour e.g. ***WHERE column_name LIKE'%' + NCHAR(0x5F) + '%'***

The solution was simply to use square brackets between the special character I wanted to search for in the column.

**Example**

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE column_name LIKE '%[_]%'
```